# in golang target, what is the alternative to parsetreeproperty?

Tags: go, antlr, antlr4

in golang target, what is the alternative to parsetreeproperty or identyhashmap?

I've looked into antlr golang runtime but found nothing related.

thanks.

Comment: My answer below is quite simple: they're not present in the Go target. If you have any further questions, consider creating a new question on SO and explain what actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

By GoLang just use map[antlr.ParserRuleContext]<user_value_type> is fine.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR targets always have (usually small) differences. The class [ParseTreeProperty](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeProperty.java) is not present in the Go target.

And the class [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) is not from the ANTLR API, but is a core Java class. So if something similar is used in the Go target, it will be a Go map/dictionary-like data structure.